# Static file caching in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, static-files

I am trying to enable static file caching but seems like no effect, at least in browser i could not find response header with name cache-control

This is my code

```
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            RequestPath = _settings.SpaRoute,                
        });


            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    // Cache static files for 30 days
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=2592000");
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Expires", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            });
```

After building and running my app in local env i got the following response headers

[image]

As you can see no cache control header represented here, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there another `app.UseStaticFiles` before what's shown here?

Comment: Also, `Cache-Control` is enough by itself, no need for `Expires`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control, or its needless date arithmetic.

Comment: There are another app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); middleware before that

Comment: Updated code part in post

Comment: It is short-circuiting the request and sending a response before your code here has a chance to. Place the `OnPrepareResponse` inside the options you pass into `UseSpaStaticFiles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StaticFileMiddleware` is a [terminal middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), i.e. it short-circuits the request and never calls the next middleware in chain if it comes across a static file request that doesn't match an endpoint ([among other conditions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/56d80d44ac7dae3048de73b4400378514318a69e/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFileMiddleware.cs#L72-L94)).

This means if you have multiple calls to `app.UseStaticFiles()`, it will insert `StaticFileMiddleware` in the middleware chain more than once and only the first one in the chain will handle the request, the rest will stay dormant.

Put a breakpoint inside a controller action and check the call stack and see if there are more than one `StaticFileMiddleware` in the stack. If you do, remove the unused ones, or move the configuration you have here into the first one.

In your code, you seem to have [`app.UseSpaStaticFiles`, which calls `app.UseStaticFiles`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/56d80d44ac7dae3048de73b4400378514318a69e/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/StaticFiles/SpaStaticFilesExtensions.cs#L114), so it's taking effect before your own `app.UseStaticFiles(/*custom options*/)`.

To solve the problem, simply pass the `OnPrepareResponse` into that middleware:

```cs
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    RequestPath = _settings.SpaRoute, 
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        // Cache static files for 30 days
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=2592000");
    }               
});
```

Comment: One more question, let's say i have an image for my  main site and i  cache that image for a 1 year because i am not going to change for a long time . But after a while, in some day i have decide to change that image and  take another one, what should i do in that case? Is there a mechanism to determine whether that file has been changed or no and load the new file and cache it?

Comment: You can add a version suffix to that asset that changes every time it's changed. Once the asset URL changes, browser will fetch the new file and cache that instead. For Razor templates, you have [`asp-append-version` tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/image-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-append-version). For UI frameworks, it depends on what you use. If you're using webpack you can add version/hash to filenames https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/.

Comment: If all else fails you can simply append a version yourself: `<img src="logo.svg" />` -> `<img src="logo.svg?v=20210722" />`

Comment: Thanks, can you pleasse explain logic behind this 

public,max-age=2592000 = 30 days ? What if i would like to cache only 3 day ? How this algorithms should be calculated?

Comment: You need to specify the duration in seconds: `(3 days) * (24hr / day) * (60min / hr) * (60sec / min) = 259200 sec` -> so you need to use `public,max-age=259200`. As for the meaning of other directives, MDN is a good starting point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0):

Use static files is sufficient, at least in .NET 6...

```cs
appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot")),
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "public, max-age: 604800";
    }
});
```